# Is this equation nondimensionalized?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

the question as mentioned in title. i want to know how this equation  is dimenssionless as my efforts didn't give me the answer 
the equation is:

$$z=(L/ \hbar) \cdot \sqrt{2m \cdot (E+V_o)}$$

as i tried in draft i found :

[z]=m.Kg.s^-1

but in the solution sheet it's a dimensionless quantity.
where z is the dimensionless quantity 
\hbar is 2* \pi * h  (h: planck's constant)
m is the mass of particle E and Vo are the energies of the system

Comment: could you explain why the sqrt has momentum units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: It seems $L$ is not angular momentum, but some length.

For the SI units we have:
$$
[L] = \text{m} \\
[\hbar] = \text{J}\text{s} = (\text{kg}\cdot (\text{m}/\text{s})^2) s 
= \text{m}^2 \cdot \text{kg} / \text{s}
$$
And
$$
[m] = \text{kg} \\
[E] = J = \text{kg}\cdot (\text{m}/\text{s})^2 \\
\left[\sqrt{m(E+V_0)}\right]=
\text{kg}\cdot (\text{m}/\text{s}) = [p]
$$
Combined we get:
$$
\frac{\text{m}}{\text Js} \frac{\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}}{\text{s}}
=\frac{\text{J}}{\text{J}} = 1
$$

Comment: i think you made a mistake in the first line [L] has units of length [L]=m only 
so [L]/[\hbar] gives s/(m \cdot kg) when you multiply by the remainming term above \sqrt{2m \cdot (E+V_0)} the result appears as 1

Comment: Here we could be onto something. I considered $L$ to be angular momentum, but you say $L$ is meant as distance.

Comment: sorry i would be able to mention for this
L: the width of finite square well
anyway i think it's clear now 
since we have units of energy and length and momentum  we can conclude it easily